# What's the difference between 29.97p and 29.97fps?

Tags: video, premiere, framerate

I'm working in Premiere and I've got one video file that isn't working for me, it's just showing as green. My initial research said to make sure the aspect and frame rates matched up between the video file and the sequence, and the only difference I can see is one is 29.97p, and the other is 29.97fps. What's the difference?

Comment: The green screen isn't related to the frame rate values. Premiere can't recognize or decode the video because either it doesn't recognize the codec tag or it doesn't expect that codec stream in that media container or the pixel format isn't supported by the decoder..etc. Will need to see the output by the Mediainfo tool linked in @Jim Mack's answer.

Answer (score 3):

A 29.97p (p = ***progressive***) video is 29.97fps (fps = ***frames per second***) but not all 29.97 fps video will be progressive. Some will be ***interlaced***, (29.97i) having 59.94 "fields" per frame.

So there may be no difference at all. If Premiere doesn't indicate whether the files are interlaced or progressive, use a tool like [**MediaInfo**](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo).